# Pass a value from a Table to another Table

Tags: mysql

I have this table, its name is puntajes:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------+
| estudiante_ID | evaluacion_ID | puntaje |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
|             1 |             1 |      15 |
|             2 |             1 |      11 |
|             3 |             1 |      17 |
|             4 |             1 |      12 |
|             1 |             2 |      13 |
|             2 |             2 |       8 |
|             3 |             2 |      15 |
|             4 |             2 |      16 |
|             1 |             3 |       9 |
|             2 |             3 |      14 |
|             3 |             3 |       9 |
|             4 |             3 |      10 |
|             1 |             4 |      15 |
|             2 |             4 |      16 |
|             3 |             4 |       9 |
|             4 |             4 |      12 |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

And I want to get the max score from puntaje column where evaluacion_ID is equal to 3, i want this value to be in the 'maxpuntaje 'column in the evaluaciones table, like an update , this is evaluaciones table:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fecha         | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tipo          | enum('P','E')    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| maxpuntaje    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clase_ID      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| evaluacion_ID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

both of the tables have the evaluacion_ID column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've commented out WHERE conditions that limit the UPDATE and maximum puntaje value retrieval so that your query could be run for all `evaluacion_ID`. If you need it only for 3, remove the comment marks.

Using MySQL UPDATE JOIN syntax:

```
UPDATE evaluaciones e
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT evaluacion_ID, MAX(puntaje) maxpuntaje
  FROM puntajes
  -- WHERE evaluacion_ID = 3
  GROUP BY evaluacion_ID
  ) p USING (evaluacion_ID)
SET maxpuntaje = p.maxpuntaje
-- WHERE e.evaluacion_ID = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're looking for this query:

```
UPDATE evaluaciones
SET maxpuntaje = (
  SELECT max(puntaje)
  FROM puntajes
  WHERE evaluacion_ID = evaluaciones.evaluacion_ID
)
WHERE evaluacion_ID = 3
```